# Spring - Relation between Dependency Injection and @Autowire

Tags: java, spring

Today in an Interview, the interviewer asked me, "**Tell me... What is Dependency Injection and Why shall we use this?"**. To that, I replied with the conventional definition of DI and IoC and how DI helps to make the code loosely coupled by not creating an object using new and explained to provide an object as the method parameter at the runtime with the spellchecker program.

```
public class TextEditor {

private IocSpellChecker checker;

public TextEditor(IocSpellChecker checker) {
    this.checker = checker;
}
```

}

He seemed not so satisfied with my bookish answer and asked me for a real-time problem which dependency injection is supposed to eliminate and he also hinted that it has got to do something with bean instantiation and memory optimization.He also mentioned it is related to @Autowire.

I have no clue of this after hours of Google search. What should be the answer to the question? How these all are related?

Comment: If you said "loose coupling", "programming to interfaces", and "Don't call us, we'll call you" you captured it.  Gotcha answers like this aren't useful.  Maybe you're better off not working for such people.  The  bean factory works with annotations like @Autowired to create and manage beans.  Have no idea if that's what the interviewer had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the *memory optimization* I could imagine he meant that DI helps getting existing object instances for reuse, instead of creating a new instance because of laziness to pass the existing object. 
The (e.g. Spring-)context manages your beans and cares about the assignment/injection. Prior to that you had to use singletons or keep all your shared objects as a member in a static or singleton class and this class has been referenced from everywhere.

Comment: Thank you @Felix for your time and effort to put forward this answer. It would be more helpful for me if you could elaborate the sentence "DI helps avoiding creating duplicate object instances for several use cases, since you can always easily get the bean injected". Can you explain this sentence in somewhat simple terms. I am unable to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most beneficial aspect of DI is that it makes the code more testable and flexible. With DI, as dependencies can be injected at run time, it is much easier to mock different implementations and test the code.

Check the Benefits of Dependency Injection section of this post for further reading:
http://www.javacreed.com/why-should-we-use-dependency-injection/

But, with memory optimization maybe he meant that as the system creates the object and injects it, it is more optimized (as it is automated). But, i am not sure if there is some kind of performance boost with DI. Will check and get back to this.

Comment: Hi @Ambidextrous... Thank you for the answer!! I too explained the interviewer in terms of it's easiness to test and how the entire system becomes loosely coupled. But he said these all are bookish answer and he wanted a real problem that is sorted out by DI.

Comment: @New2Java not sure what else he wanted. Your answer looks completely fine to me. Couldn't find any kind of performance boost due to DI. But, another good article for your reference: http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/10/benefits-of-dependency-injection.html#.WutOGNTwa2w